# Get Div to Slide out and back on click

Tags: jquery, show-hide, sliding

I have this sidebar of sales info that I want to slide out and back on click. Right now it will slide out but it won't slide back once I have clicked it once. If someone could figure out why the code won't work that would be great.

Also, I want the div to move a little to the left when you hover but only when it is all the way to the left. I am doing this to make it a little more noticeable that it is able to be clicked.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="sidebar">
<div id="sales">
    <div id="salesbar">
        <img id="sales_img" src="/images/sales.png"/>
            <h3>Contact Sales</h3>
            <p>
                For more information 
                please email us or call:
            </p>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var sales = $('#sales', '#sidebar'),
            image = $('#sales_img', '#salesbar'),
            rt = sales.css('right');
    image.click(function(event) {           
        if(rt == '0px' || rt == '5px') {
            sales.animate({
                'right':'235px'
            }, 600); 
        } else {
            sales.animate({
                'right': '0px'
                }, 600);
        }
            event.preventDefault();
    }); 
sales.hover(
        function() {
            if(rt == '0px' || rt == '5px') {
                sales.css('right','5px');
            }
        }, function () {
            if(rt == '5px') {
                sales.css('right', '0px');
            }
        }
    );

    });
```

To summarize, I would like to click once on the sales bar and have it pop out and stay there. Then when you click on it again, go back to where it started. If possible, it would be great if when you hover it moves over 5px then on the way out goes back.

Here is the jsfiddle with the css as well: http://jsfiddle.net/yzvswLwx/1/

Thanks in advanced

Comment: [See if this link will help](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions/)

Comment: @dragonslovetacos That's the right idea but I still want some of the content showing before and after. Also, I want the action to be on the element itself.

Comment: @dragonslovetacos After a little messing around, that link helped a bit. I just couldn't get the hover that I was using to help.

Comment: Awesome. I knew it wasn't exactly what you were trying to do, but thought it might help get you un-stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is the effect you are after, but see if this helps;

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var sales = $('#sales', '#sidebar'),
        image = $('#sales_img', '#salesbar'),
        rt = sales.css('right');
    image.click(function (event) {
        if (rt == '0px' || rt == '5px') {
            sales.animate({
                'right': '235px'
            }, 600);
        } else {
            sales.animate({
                'right': '0px'
            }, 600);
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    image.hover(function () {
        if (sales.css('right') == '0px') {
            sales.css('right', '5px');
        }
    });
    $('#sales').mouseleave(function () {
        var pos = sales.css('right').substr(0, sales.css('right').length - 2);
        if (pos > 5) sales.animate({
            'right': '0px'
        }, 600);
    });
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/yzvswLwx/12/

Comment: thanks a bunch. I didn't use your click function but the hover with the conditional worked great. Since the hover function takes two arguments, I added the second with another conditional for when mouseleave.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work. Thanks a bunch @Baps for the hover and @dragonslovetacos for the click function.

Here is what I went with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var sales = $('#sales', '#sidebar'),
            image = $('#sales_img', '#salesbar'),
            rt = sales.css('right');


  image.click(function() {
    var $marginLefty = $('#sales');
    $marginLefty.animate({
      right: parseInt($marginLefty.css('right'),10) === 5 ?
        $marginLefty.outerWidth()-image.outerWidth(true) :
        0
    });
  });

image.hover(
    function () {
    if (sales.css('right') == '0px') {
        sales.css('right', '5px');
    }
    }, function() {
    if(sales.css('right') == '5px') {
        sales.css('right','0px');
        }
    }
    );        
});
```